# Can I reference the media size in responsive css instructions?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am familiar with setting rules using media queries for breakpoints in responsive CSS however I want to know if I can use the same method for providing the CSS with instructions for formatting a class/object?

E.g. can I have something along the lines of

```
#image {
    max-width:([whatever the media width is]-20) px;
}
```

?

Comment: are you trying to do `calc(100% - 20px)`? could you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since media width is 100% you can use it using calc() method:

```
#image {
    max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

See browser [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).